# По поводу межсайтовой подделки запросов?

Tags: asp.net, backend, authenticationtoken, malware

Если злоумышленник внедряет на свой сайт JS-код, который через куки пользователя проворачивает свои дела, то как X-CRSF и тому подобные токены, которые хранятся как куки, должны помочь?

Comment: javascript имеет доступ не ко всем кукам. Плюс CSRF токен никак не помогает, если у злоумышленника есть доступ к открытой странице пользователя

Comment: @Grundy Нет, ну там же просто с помощью JS производится запрос на сайт. А всё остальное уже делает браузер, если я правильно понял.

Comment: Не важно, кто нажмет кнопку "отправить" пользователь или скрипт. CSRF токен тут никак не связан

Comment: @Grundy Но почему? Допустим, зловредный JS код вынуждает отправлять сначала запрос к странице, где получается токен, а затем вынуждает отправлять POST-запрос. Вот и весь обход защиты.

Comment: Не понял, как это относится к моим комментариям

Comment: @Grundy Вы сказали, что CSRF токен никак не связан с отправкой запросов. Я возразил, и расписал, в чём именно несогласен.

Comment: В моих комментариях речь шла про внедрение js код на странице сайта. Я не правильно понял _Если злоумышленник внедряет на свой сайт JS-код,_ в котором имелось ввиду что запросы идут с другого сайта. В моих комментариях речь про запросы с целевого сайта, в случае если злоумышленник встроил js код в него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Атаки CSRF основаны на том, что authentication cookie отправляются браузером автоматически.

Защита через токены основана на том, что сайт проверяет не наличие куки, а наличие значения из куки в дополнительном хедере.

Код на странице сайта может взять значение из куки и положить его в отдельный хедер. Сервер проверяет, что значение в куке и в хедере совпало. Т.е. запрос от вашего сайта будет выглядеть так:

```
Cookies: X-CSRF=abc
X-CSRF: abc
```

Сторонний сайт может отправить запрос на ваш сайт, но не может достать значение из куки и прислать его в доп хедере. Он может только отправить запрос без значения в доп хедере. Запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
Cookies: X-CSRF=abc
```

И сервер его завернет.

CRSF в современных браузерах предотвращается через [SameSite=Lax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite) по умолчанию для кук, так что можете не заморачиватся с дополнительной защитой.

Comment: Спасибо, что рассказали. Огромный респект и уважение, как говорится. Отметил ваш ответ как решение.

Comment: На MDN написано, что Lax до сих пор не по умолчанию в Firefox и Safari :(

Comment: Единственный момент хотелось бы уточнить: а вот если злоумышленник сделает так: перенаправит сначала на JS код ( например, на /static/js/test.chunk.js ), который помещает значение кука в хедер, а потом перенаправит на нужную страницу. Такое возможно?

Comment: @CsHarpUser да, поэтому у вас не должно быть js скриптов, которые при чистом своем выполнении что-то сами по себе делают. ну или иначе такие скрипты - это аналог страницы на вашем сайте, которая просто при открытии делает что-то дейтвительно важное. если имелся ввиду сначала запрос к js, а потом запрос к нужной странице - то нет, такое не сработает - заголовок нужно добавлять вручную в каждый запрос, на втором запросе его просто не будет.

Comment: @PashaPash Спасибо большое!